# How can I order a MySql result with an exception?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm running this query on a MYSql database:

```
select * from wp_postmeta
where meta_key LIKE "%_thumbnail_id"
and post_id = 897
```

It is returning this data set:

[Picture.png http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/9065/picturezo.png](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/9065/picturezo.png)

How can I order by `meta_key` so that `_thumbnail_id` comes first, then followed by `dogs_image-2_thumbnail_id` and then `dogs_image-3_thumbnail_id` ?

If I simply use `order by meta_key asc` the numbered images are in order, but `_thumbnail_id` is showing up at the bottom instead of the top.

Comment: Is it pure chance that the meta_value column is in the order you want?

Comment: How did you do it to get the result set the way you want in the image?

Comment: running it with no "order by" clause returns it in that order, but i think it is just by chance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key LIKE "%_thumbnail_id" AND post_id = 897
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ASC, meta_key
```

I am assuming that **_thumbnail_id** is the only odd case you have.

Comment: i selected this one as correct b/c of the nice job formatting with capitals for mysql commands, even though @nick rulez answer worked perfectly too.

Comment: @Cwd yeah I am a little OCD when it comes to SQL formatting :D glad the solution worked for you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from wp_postmeta
where meta_key LIKE "%_thumbnail_id"
and post_id = 897
order by case when meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' then 0 else 1 end, meta_key
```

Answer (score 0):

introduce additional `order` column and make two columns sort

```
create table test (
     (...)
     meta_key varchar(255), 
     `order` integer default 1000,
     key (`order`, `meta_key`) -- optional, more disk space usage, faster sorting
)

-- then do
select * from `test` order by `order`, `meta_key`
```

you will of course have to maintain order column value manually (i.e. for 'exceptions' give greater or smaller value than default)
this will also cost you some space for two column index

or better solution would be to sort data somewhere else than db (you query it from some kind of script, dont you?).

or introduce some if - case nightmare, like suggested in other answers - but this will make your indices useless so it will be performance nightmare for big tables.

Comment: thats why better solution is to code it elsewhere. I would call having nasty ifs trashing indices usage in db for sorting an overkill - except maybe 'one time, manual query execution situations'

Comment: I guess I meant that the `case` function above just looked like a simpler solution. but thanks for this perspective.